# How to block videos by title on youtube using Squid?

Tags: windows, windows-7, squid, blocking

For example,i want to block videos that contain the word "cat" in the title.
I also do not want the blocked videos appearing in:

-Recommended Channels tab

-Recommended/related videos

-Search results

Basically i am trying to imitate this:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk?hl=en

Also,can you please provide your answer step-by-step with instructions.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software called squidGuard that lets you define rules and block content based on those rules. It is quite flexible. You simply bind it to your existing squid installation through squid.conf.

http://www.squidguard.org/

Comment: :just installed squidguard,can you please show me some tutorials on how to block video by title name?  Thank you for your time.